# Find the lowest value of $n$, such that the equation $p^{2}+pq+q^{2}=n$ has only five solutions

Tags: number-theory

Let $1\le p<q$ natural numbers such that $p^{2}+pq+q^{2}=n$
Find the lowest value of $n$ so that the equation has only five solutions

is very hard

---

Notes edited in by MF

If $\eta(n)$ is the number of $p,q>p$ pairs such that $n=p^2+pq+q^2$, the (lowest) numbers  $\alpha_k: \eta(\alpha_k) = k$ are fascinating:

The first number with $\eta(n) = 4$ is $1729$, which is interesting for other reasons, and is divisible by $13$.  In fact, all lowest numbers $\alpha_k$ for $k>1$ apparently are divisible by $13$:
$$
\eta(91) = 2\\
\eta(637) = 3\\
\eta(1729) = 4\\
\eta(\mbox{answer to the question}) = 5\\
\eta(12103) = 6\\
\eta(53599) = 8
$$
The problem is particularly nice since $a_5 > \alpha_6$

An even harder problem is to determine $\alpha_7$ which is more than $266000$ even though $\alpha_8 < 53600$.

Comment: You mean exactly five solutions (not $5$ or fewer), right?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @MarkFischler only 5 solutions such that $p<q$

Comment: How the heck is this "off topic"?

Comment: @Mark Fischler: I agree. An interesting question doesn't need a "context" - it is its own context.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going with $7^4×13=31213$.  Three of the solutions are obtained by multiplying the solutions for $637$ by $7^2$:

$637 \rightarrow (4,23)$ thus $31213\rightarrow (28,161)$

$637 \rightarrow (7,21)$ thus $31213 \rightarrow (49,147)$

$637 \rightarrow (12,17)$ thus $31213 \rightarrow (84,119)$

Render the additional factor of $7^2$ as $3^2+(3×5)+5^2$ and use the multiplicative properties of Eisenstein integers to generate exactly two additional, primitive solutions:

$31213 \rightarrow (9,172)$

$31213 \rightarrow (101,103)$

Let us delve more deeply into how those two primitive solutions come about.  We have, for $637$ and $49$ respectively:

$637=4^2+(4×23)+23^2$

$49=3^2+(5×3)+5^2$

An Eisenstein integer has the form $a+b\omega $ where $\omega $ is a primitive cube root of unity.  The norm of $p-q\omega $ (Note the negative sign) is then $\sqrt{p^2+pq+q^2}$.  Thus

$|4-23\omega |=\sqrt{637}$

$|3-5\omega |=\sqrt{49}=7$

Now just multiply the Eisenstein integers , eliminating $\omega ^2$ by rendering it as $-1-\omega$.  Then the product is:

$|-103-204\omega |=\sqrt{31213}$

This does not correspond to a positive integer solution for $p$ and $q$ because that requires the integer coefficients to have mixed signs!  But we can multiply $-103-204\omega$ by $\omega$ to get

$|101-103\omega |=\sqrt{31213}$

$101^2+(101×103)+103^2=31213$

To get the $(9,172)$ solution we multiply $12-17\omega$ by $5-3\omega$, reversing the order of the $7^2$ decomposition.  All other possible multiplications using Eisenstein integers from the solutions for $637$ and $49$ repeat the three nonprimitive solutions obtained directly from $31213=637×7^2$, or the two primitive solutions already proposed.

Comment: For $k=7$ the lowest $n$ is equal to $405769$.

Comment: Equal to $7^4×13^2$.  This is actually ingenious, using the fact that $7×2+1$ is composite to get a lower solution than I would have thought of!  Turn that into an answer maybe?

Comment: For $k=5$ the solution is, I think, less than $31213$, somewhaer around $22,500$. .

Answer (score 4):

All the $\alpha_k$ (the smallest integers with $k$ ways to decompose as 
$p^2+pq+q^2$ that I have been able to find are divisible by $13$. The answer to the problem is $\alpha_5 = 31213 = 7^4\cdot 13$.  The  $\alpha_k$ seem to love prime factors of the form $6r+1$ and hate prime factors of the form $6r-1$.

$$\begin{array}{rl} 
\alpha_2 = & 91 = 7 \cdot 13 \\ 
\alpha_3 = & 637 = 7^2 \cdot 13 \\ 
\alpha_4 = & 1729 = 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \\ 
\alpha_5 = & 31213 = 7^4 \cdot 13 \\ 
\alpha_6 = & 12103 = 7^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19\\ 
\alpha_7 = & 405769 = 7^4 \cdot 13^2 \\ 
\alpha_8 = & 53599 = 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 31\\ 
\alpha_9 = & 157339 =7^2 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19 \\ 
\alpha_{10} = & 593047 = 7^4 \cdot 13 \cdot 19\\  
\alpha_{11} = & 7^{10}×13 (**)\\
\alpha_{12} = & 375193 = 7^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 31\\  
\alpha_{13} = & 2989441 = 7^2 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19^2 \\  
\alpha_{14} = & 29059303 = 7^6 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \\  
\alpha_{15} = & 7709611 = 7^4 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19 \\  
\alpha_{16} = & 1983163 = 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 \cdot 37\\  
\alpha_{17} = & 7^6×13^4 (**)\\  
\alpha_{18} = & 4877509 = 7^2 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 \\  
\alpha_{19} = & 7^{12}×13^2 (**)\\  
\alpha_{20} = & 18384457 = 7^4 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 \\  
\alpha_{21} = & 377770939 = 7^6 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19  \\  
\alpha_{22} = & 146482609 = 7^4 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19^2  \\  
\alpha_{24} = & 13882141 = 7^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 \cdot 37\\  
\alpha_{27} = & 92671671 = 7^2 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 31 \\  
\end{array}
$$

** - expected result based on prime factorizations.

The value given now for $\alpha_9$ lower than that quoted originally; it was verified as having nine positive solutions by exhaustive search.  With three distinct prime factor $2^{3-1}=4$ of the nine solutions are primitive, the rest nonprimitive.

Comment: How did you get these?

Comment: $\alpha_{11}=7^{10}×13$, $\alpha_{17}=7^6×13^4$.

Comment: @Marty we can count off positive integer solutions from the prime factorization.  Given a product of $6k+1$ primes (there are none other in minimal solutions), add $1$ to each exponent and then multiply the incremented exponents.  Divide the product by $2$ and discard the remainder if present, the quotient is the number of positive solutions.  Example:  $7^4×13$ gives $(4+1)×(1+1)=10$, divide by $2$ to get a quotient of $5$, therefore five positive solutions.

Comment: Is the a product formula for numbers of the form $p^2+pq+q^2$ like there is for two and four squares?

Comment: In Eisenstein integers $(p_1-q_1\omega)×(p_2-q_2\omega)=(p_1p_2-q_1q_2)-(p_1q_2+p_2q_1+q_1q_2)\omega$.  So $(p_1^2+p_1q_1+q_1^2)×(p_2^2+p_2q_2+q_2^2)=(p_1p_2-q_1q_2)^2+(p_1p_2-q_1q_2)×(p_1q_2+p_2q_1+q_1q_2)+(p_1q_2+p_2q_1+q_1q_2)^2$.

Comment: I got these by coding a tiny program that processed all $p$ up to $4000$ and all $q>p$ up to $8000$, counting the number of times each $n$ occurred. The reason I did not find $\alpha_{11}$ is that this technique only fully covers all $n$ up to about 36 million, and  $\alpha_{11}$ is a hundred times bigger than that. @Oscar Lanzi I am curious as to how you know there is no smaller value of $n$ with $\eta(n)=11$?

Comment: @Mark $7^{10}×13$ is the smallest prime factor product that will give incremented exponents with a product of either $2×11=22$ or $2×11+1=23$.  Basically we are doing the same thing with $6k+1$ primes that we would do with $4k+1$ primes for the corresponding $p^2+q^2$ problem.   See my previous comment.

Comment: Due to time limits for editing I must add another comment.  @Mark the referenced comment  is the one posted at approximately 6 July, 02:00 utc.